# Write an EventLog entry with the actual time as content

Tags: powershell, scripting, messagebox, event-log

I would like to write an `EventLog` entry with the actual time as the content. 
I already tried a lot without success.

Comment: I tried everything you did and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Write-EventLog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849847(v=wps.620).aspx) and [Get-Date](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113313) cmdlet...

```
Write-EventLog -logname Application -source MyApp -eventID 3001 -entrytype Information -message (Get-Date).ToString() -category 1
```